# Makefile - Pattern Rules

Tags: makefile

I am new to writing makefiles. Recently I have seen pattern rules in makefiles. For example:

```
%.o: %.cc
        # command to compile comes here
```

After rigourous searching in the net, I found out what the above statement does,
But I came across another statement below.

```
%: %.o
        # Command to link lies here
```

I do not understand this rule. Can anyone explain the second pattern rule?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second rule is also a pattern rule, it says how to make a file with no extension from a file with the same name, but `.o` at the end. So it's a rule to link `foo` from `foo.o`, `bar` from `bar.o` and so on.

Comment: Thanks Jack, your post answered my question.